# Get certain part of a string

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I am getting a little piece of code from a client to a server, which looks like this:

```
"NAME: " & My.Computer.Name & "; IP: " & GetExternalIp()
```

This Code is beeing recieved by the server in a textbox(txt.Chat) with multiline.. So I'm actually kind of re-asking this, because the question I asked wasn't really understandable. Some user answered this:

```
Dim stringFromClient As String = "Name: xxx-PC; IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 
Dim values() As String = stringFromClient.Split(";")
Dim name As String = values(0).Split(":").Last.Trim
Dim IP As String = values(1).Split(":").Last.Trim
Debug.Print("name = " & name)
Debug.Print("IP = " & IP)
```

I tried this out, but the problem was that I was getting this output: "Name: xxx-PC; IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" which isn't actually what i want.. i dont know how to set the "stringfromClient" string correctly.

Comment: ok, you've told us what doesn't work and that you want to `set the "stringfromClient" string correctly` but what is "the certain part" you want?

Comment: the certain part is once the part AFTER "Name:" until the ; and then the part AFTER "IP:" until the end. these are the 2 things i want

Comment: What do you mean with stringFromServer? im not even getting a string from the server its just beeing displayed by the server but it is from the client.

Comment: Im sorry, the code was posted from a user and he called it stringfromserver, but theres no string from the server to i changed it to client, but forgot to change the other one too, my bad :)

Comment: We still don't know what the problem is though.

Comment: Code works.  It's not clear where the multi-line part comes into play, which I'm guessing is the crux of the issue.

Comment: The Problem is, if i do: `Dim stringFromClient As String = "Name: xxx-PC; IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ` i gives me out as Name xxx-PC and as IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but i want to get from the recieved line the Name which would be for example: "Name: Jon-PC; IP: 127.0.0.1".

Comment: Well, how are we supposed to know where you get your data from?  Where is that string of information coming from?

Comment: Well maybe i dont know eiter.. If i would send this code to a random person, it should be able to give me that information.

Comment: Still confused.  Would your string be: `Dim stringFromClient As String = "NAME: " & My.Computer.Name & "; IP: " & GetExternalIp()`  Is that what you are trying to figure out?

Comment: Haha i know why you are confused, but yes i guess thats what im trying to figure out.. Paul Coldrey alread posted that i should do it, and i tried but it only gives me my information and i dont have someone that could test it out so i need to wait till tomorrow so i can send it a friend to test it.

Answer (score 0):

To set the string do this:

```
Dim stringFromSomewhere As String = "NAME: " & My.Computer.Name & "; IP: " & GetExternalIp()
```

To extract the values do this:

```
Dim values() As String = stringFromSomewhere .Split(";")
Dim name As String = values(0).Split(":").Last.Trim
Dim IP As String = values(1).Split(":").Last.Trim
Debug.Print("name = " & name)
Debug.Print("IP = " & IP)
```

"name" and "IP" will contain the name and IP data from the original string

Comment: Thanks dude, it actually splits the String correctly, i just need to wait until tomorrow so a friend can test it)

Comment: Well this is not working. I showed the Name and the Ip in a textbox. When i start the tool it says Marcel-PC and My IP. But when im recieving a line now from a friend, it doesnt insert the new line into the textbox.

Comment: Yep - so that tells you that _this_ code works perfectly but there is something wrong in how you are sending / receiving the stringFromServer/Client.

Comment: Ok, but i have one question to the code, where does is read out the recieved line? from the textbox

Comment: That is the important question that depends entirely on your implementation. It appears you are trying to send this information in some way between the applications so I would expect it might  be read from a string that is sent via a socket? But, where is comes from depends entirely on your implementation. If you are getting information from a remote app then you _could_ use that to fill a value in a textbox (and that would be a good debugging step). But, this question appears to relate to how to extract the data not how to send it.

Comment: Well im getting the Information via TCP.. Im getting the Information into the txtbox called txtChat.. Well i dont really know how to do this stringFromSomewhere.. I thought of something like: Every new Line that gets added in txtChat, do the whole splitting process.. But i didnt find any useful code which does the every new line part and i could actually do: `Dim stringFromSomewhere as string = txtChat.Text` but that doesnt work either, because it just takes the first line and not every new line recieved.